# Querying Firebase on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my data:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "00c49c66-7ac8-9a48-7c4541d8bac6" : {
      "email" : "d@gmail.com",
      "gender" : "m",
      "name" : "deepak",
      "user_id" : "00c49c66-7ac8-9a48-7c4541d8bac6"
    },
    "1cb9c1de-1fcf-a2cc-bf78c84e03c8" : {
      "email" : "e@gmail.com",
      "gender" : "f",
      "name" : "ekta",
      "user_id" : "1cb9c1de-1fcf-a2cc-bf78c84e03c8"
    },
    "38211c3f-6c48-8987-0c698b9b9b52" : {
      "email" : "c@gmail.com",
      "gender" : "m",
      "name" : "chirag",
      "user_id" : "38211c3f-6c48-8987-0c698b9b9b52"
    },
    "a536cf1f-419f-9658-cfb5f5a8ec78" : {
      "email" : "a@gmail.com",
      "gender" : "m",
      "name" : "aniket",
      "user_id" : "a536cf1f-419f-9658-cfb5f5a8ec78"
    },
    "c80d828d-48d7-a79a-9cc558cd1960" : {
      "email" : "b@gmail.com",
      "gender" : "f",
      "name" : "bhakti",
      "user_id" : "c80d828d-48d7-a79a-9cc558cd1960"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to **get 'name' and 'id' where 'gender' is "m"**

Please can anyone tell me how to fire a query like this from Android client to firebase.

I tried tutorials provided by firebase and few other links but didn't got through.

Most of solutions are in Javascript I need it for Android in firebase's java api.

I tried this

```
public class ActivityHome extends Activity {
    String strLoggedInUserID;
    TextView tvData;
    Firebase fbRef = new Firebase("https://myurl.com/users");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        tvData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvData);

        Query queryRef = fbRef.orderByChild("gender").equalTo("m");

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        strLoggedInUserID = extras.getString("userID");

        fbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

        queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                //long longChildCount = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

                // tvData.setText(dataSnapshot).toString();
                tvData.setText(s);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            //tvData.setText(s);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your querying code looks correct, but you're not printing the user.

Since you're adding a `ChildEventListener`, it will be called for each child:

```
queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        //long longChildCount = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

        // tvData.setText(dataSnapshot).toString();
        tvData.setText(s);

    }
```

The `dataSnapshot` parameter contains information about a single user. To print their key, name and email:

```
queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.key());
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue());
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue());
    }
```

Alternatively, you can listen to all children at once with a `ValueEventListener`.

```
private static class User {
    String email;
    String gender;
    String name;
    @JsonProperty("user_id")
    String userId;

    public String getEmail() { return email; }
    public String getGender() { return gender; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getUserId() { return userId; }
}
queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            User user = child.getValue(User.class);
            System.out.println(user.getEmail());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
});
```

In this last snippet I also use a `User` class for getting the data from `DataSnapshot`. As your application grows, this will be more convenient than constantly calling `DataSnapshot.child()`.

This is covered in the [section on reading data in the Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html).

Comment: Thank You Sir @Frank van Puffelen as started working on app might need more help :)

Comment: Before continuing on your app, you'd do well to read the entire programming guide that I linked to. A few hours day will save you a lot of time and questions down the line.